# problem on sdcard

Tags: sd-card

I got my raspberry pi kit today morning, with an SD card. My problem is I can't understand if the operating system is installed on the SD card. I don't have a power cable or display cable to test. However, when I put the SD card in my laptop it shows some binary files and .db files. What can I do for this problem?

Comment: you should see something like this when you insert the SD card in your computer: http://i.imgur.com/cInTI5c.png

Answer (score 1):

"Some binary and db files" is a likely indication that the card contains the OS. You can easily armour your card with any of the available linux distros by following simple instructions [from here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

The boot partition type is fat32. The other partitions are ext4 and swap. So, when you use the SD card in Windows you only see the boot partition. This partition has the following files:

- config.txt
- Some firmware

So if you see this files you have a system.

Answer (score 1):

You should see the following files on your SD card somewhere. I believe it is required that the boot partition contain them but not 100% sure on that requirement:

- bootcode.bin
- start.elf
- kernel.img
- cmdline.txt

See: [Raspberry Pi Advanced Boot Partition Setup](http://elinux.org/RPi_Advanced_Setup#Setting_up_the_boot_partition)